# Uanble to Install Jekyll - macOS Catalina

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, exit-code, macos-catalina, gemspecs

I am running Catalina (10.15.3) and am attempting to install Jekyll. When I do I appear to have the bundler install correctly but then have issues as shown below. Am a relative noob to working with terminal/Ruby etc. so any help would be appreciated. (or point me in the direction of a post that addresses this issue(s))

Updated install errors/information below:

```
gem install --user-install bundler jekyll
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Eric/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200317-12383-w3d9nm.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/Eric/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

current directory: /Users/Eric/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Eric/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Eric/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
1 gem installed
```

Comment: It appears to install the bundler fine but then has issues building the gem - thoughts?

Comment: You need to install xcode, see: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139899/error-al-instalar-sass-en-mac?rq=1

Comment: @TahaBASRI 
Thank you for your response. See below. I based this off of the link you provided. Any other thoughts?

When I run 

 `xcode-select --install`

I get:

`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Then I try to run:

`sudo xcodebuild -license`

I get:

`xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall xcode from scratch and repeat these steps, also see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569) and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569)